# MYSQL select all item numbers where the timestamp is highest and quantity sold is highest

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT itemno, MAX(last_updated) as TopDate
FROM table
WHERE userID = 'user'
GROUP BY itemno) AS EachItem ON 
    EachItem.TopDate = table.last_updated 
    AND EachItem.itemno = table.itemno
```

I have taken the solution above from a previous post and modified it to work with one of the functions that I have created but I now want to use this same query but adapt it to order the result by max(last_updated) (which is a timestamp in my table) and also max(qty_sold).

Basically I have multiple duplicates of itemnos in the table but only want to return the rows with the latest date and highest qty_sold for every row where a certain user ID is specified.

Many thanks in advance, I have spent hours searching and can't figure this out as I am fairly new to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question after more trying by adding ORDER BY qty_sold DESC to the end.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT itemno, MAX(last_updated) as TopDate
FROM table
WHERE userID = 'user'
GROUP BY itemno) AS EachItem ON 
   EachItem.TopDate = table.last_updated 
   AND EachItem.itemno = table.itemno
   ORDER BY qty_sold DESC
```

Comment: I would delete the question, or otherwise improve the question by providing sample data and a desired result, and then accepting the answer - assuming it remains the best answer after taking those steps.

Comment: Huh? I asked the question then realised my mistake and answered it for others to see!!! What more could I have done to please you?

Comment: As outlined above